# How to close an open Exceldocument in F#?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2012, f#

I'searching for a function to close an opened Exceldocument.
That's how I open it:

```
let xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass()
let xlWorkBookInput = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Projects\Tool\Versuch\VersuchZuEditieren.xlsx")
let viewStateMachine state event = 
    match state, event with
    | {State = _}, ConsumablesClicked vm -> 
        view.HandleModelChanged { Title = "My Title"; Comment = sprintf "" }
        let TrackPosition = vm.TrackPosition
        let xlWorkSheetInput = xlWorkBookInput.Worksheets.["Consumables"] :?> Excel.Worksheet
        let array = vm.TubePosition.Split([|','|])
        let arrayLength = array.Length
        let addIndex = sprintf "%s%d"
        let randomNumber = System.Random()
        for i in 0 .. arrayLength - 1 do
            xlWorkSheetInput.Cells.[startindex + i + 2, 1] <- vm.TrackPosition
            xlWorkSheetInput.Cells.[startindex + i + 2, 2] <- array.[i]
            let randomBarcodePart2 = randomNumber.Next(000000, 999999)
            xlWorkSheetInput.Cells.[startindex+ i + 2, 3] <- sprintf "%s%06d" vm.FixBarcodePart randomBarcodePart2
        startindex <- startindex + arrayLength 
        { State = "Consumables" }
```

And here I will close it, but how?

Comment: From the docs it seems like `xlApp.Workbooks.Close(true)` will do what you want

Comment: Thank you for it, I must write xlApp.Workbooks.Close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments in the discussion, Excel documents can be closed with

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Close()
```